# Python Flask endless redirect loop 302

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, routes

I have currently an issue where one of my pages in flask falls into an endless redirect loop:

[image]

I have already so many routes and methodes and had never a problem with this. I also have no idea how to solve it, here is the function / route which has this problem (Its a simple mail function, couldnt even test it):

```
@app.route('/kontakt/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def kontakt_send():
    form = KontaktMailForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.check.data == 9:
            simplemail.Email(
            from_address = form.absender.data, #request.form["absender"],
            to_address = u"email@email.de",
            subject = u"Nachricht - Kontaktformular von " + form.name.data,
            message = form.nachricht.data #request.form["nachricht"]
            ).send()
            flash("Nachricht erfolgreich versandt")
            return redirect(url_for('kontakt_send'))
        else:
            flash("Was ist 4+5?")
            return redirect(url_for('kontakt_send'))
    else:
        flash("Alle Felder muessen ausgefuellt werden")
        return redirect(url_for('kontakt_send'))
    return render_template('kontakt.html', form=form)
```

I dont even know which data is relevant to solve this issue, but here is the form from the html template:

```
<form id="kontaktform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url_for('kontakt_send') }}">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.name.label }} <span class="star"> * </span>
    {{ form.name(size=30, class = "form-control", placeholder="z.B. Markus Müller") }} 
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.absender.label }} <span class="star"> * </span>
    {{ form.absender(class = "form-control", placeholder="z.B. markus.müller@gmx.de") }}  
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.nachricht.label }} <span class="star"> * </span>
    {{ form.nachricht(size=500, class = "form-control", placeholder="z.B. Ihre Nachricht an uns") }} 
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.check.label }} <span class="star"> * </span>
    {{ form.check(class = "form-control", placeholder="z.B. 9") }}   
  </div>
  
  <div class="">
  <button type="submit" class="btn mybtn"> Senden </button>
  </div>
  
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

Remiving the second `return redirect(url_for('kontakt_send'))` from the else solved the issue, but everytime I load the page it shows me the flash message eventhough I am not submitting the form, how is this possible? It submits the form by reloading the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`validate_on_submit` checks two things:

1. Is the request a POST?
2. Does the post body validate as the specified form?

If either of these is false, the else block runs and generates the flash message. Since the first check will be false for all GETs, you'll receive the flash message on every page load that isn't a form submission (this is also why you has the redirect loop). The second one will be false anytime the form doesn't validate, thus leading to the flash message again.

All of your if/else blocks lead to flash messages. That's why you get one on every request.

Comment: yeah thanks I already figured it out, but great explanation. Here you go.